# socket.gaierror in Google Data Python lib code

Tags: gdata, gdata-api

I'm trying to execute this basic code from [Getting Started with Google data](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib.html):

```
`import gdata.docs.service

# Create a client class which will make HTTP requests with Google Docs server.
client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
# Authenticate using your Google Docs email address and password.
client.ClientLogin('jo@gmail.com', 'password')

# Query the server for an Atom feed containing a list of your documents.
documents_feed = client.GetDocumentListFeed()
# Loop through the feed and extract each document entry.
for document_entry in documents_feed.entry:
  # Display the title of the document on the command line.
  print document_entry.title.text`
```

The third line i.e. `client.ClientLogin('myemail-id', 'my-password')` is throwing an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 834, in ClientLogin
    self.ProgrammaticLogin(captcha_token, captcha_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 771, in ProgrammaticLogin
    headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/http.py", line 163, in request
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1154, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Could you help me understand what this error is about and also how to work around this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing this as well.

Comment: Will, there was a proxy in-between. On configuring it correctly under Lan Settings from Tools > Internet Options under IE, the script worked out fine.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Mine ended up being a different error.

Comment: Happy to know that it worked out for you, but I am interested to know what your error was.

Comment: [I was passing the `video_id` argument to `GetYouTubeVideoEntry` incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814571/socket-error-when-using-gdata-youtube-api-in-python)