# Socket error when using gdata Youtube API in Python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I'm using `gdata` to map YouTube URLs to video titles, using the following code:

```
import gdata.youtube.service as youtube
import re
import queue
import urlparse

ytservice = youtube.YouTubeService()
ytservice.ssl = True
ytservice.developer_key = '' # snip

class youtube(mediaplugin):
  def __init__(self, parsed_url):
    self.url = parsed_url
    self.video_id = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)['v'][0]
    self.ytdata = ytservice.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(self.video_id)
    print self.ytdata
```

I get the following socket exception when calling service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry():

```
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/qpi/media.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.ytdata = ytservice.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(self.video_id)
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 210, in GetYouTubeVideoEntry
    return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntryFromString)
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1069, in Get
    headers=extra_headers)
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 93, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/service.py", line 186, in request
    data=data, headers=all_headers)
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/http_interface.py", line 148, in perform_request
    return http_client.request(operation, url, data=data, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/haldean/Documents/qpi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/http.py", line 163, in request
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 937, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 759, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1140, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I'm at a loss as to how to even begin debugging this. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit:*
In response to a question asked in comments, `video_id` is `qh-mwjF-OMo` and `parsed_url` is:

```
ParseResult(scheme=u'http', netloc=u'www.youtube.com', path=u'/watch', params='', query=u'v=qh-mwjF-OMo&feature=g-user-u', fragment='')
```

Comment: What's the values of `parsed_url` and `self.video_id`? I ask because when the library attempts to parse the address when the exception occurs.

Comment: `parsed_url` is a parsed url from `urlparse.parse_qs`, and video_id is the `v` parameter from a Youtube URL. I'll edit the question to add some info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that the `video_id` should be passed as a keyword parameter, like so:

```
    self.ytdata = ytservice.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=self.video_id)
```

It seems that the socket exception is the only layer of `gdata` that will throw an exception; it tries to get a URL blindly based on the arguments and it only fails when the URL fetch fails.